# Missing my next() when replacing my services with ngrx effects in my angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

In my app I get my data from a web api. I have my service, which looks like this:

```
getVehicles(): Observable<Vehicle[]> {
    return this.http.get<Vehicle[]>(this.API_URL).pipe(
      tap(() => this.log(`fetched vehicles`)),
      catchError(this.handleError('getVehicles', []))
    );
  }
```

And I used to have a function in my component which looked like this:

```
getVehicles(): Observable<Vehicle[]> {
    const details = this.vehicleService.getVehicles();
    return details;
  }
```

In my ngOnInit I could then do something smooth like this

```
this.getVehicleDetails().subscribe(data => {
        this.vehicleDetails = data;
        this.setMarkers();
      })
```

Now however I am using ngrx and my code is looking quite differently for obvious reasons.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    // getvehicles
    this.vehicles$ = this.store.select(fromStore.getAllVehicles);
    this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadVehicles());
}
```

The problem is that I used to be able to use my next() method in my ngOnInit to set my markers on my map with my function setMarkers(). When I called my setMarkers() outside of my old getVehicles function it used to return nothing, since my vehicles are undefined for the first seconds of initialization of the app. By using it inside the next method I could avoid that.
This is not the case anymore however, and I wonder if there is something similar I can do to be able to use my function setMarkers(), now when I have changed my code?

Comment: Are you subscribing to `this.vehicles$` somewhere in your code?  I think you need to use `this.vehicles$.subscribe( v => ...)` to get update state of vehicles

Comment: Im not subscribing to it right now, but I thought that a big reason for using ngrx is to avoid using the old method I was using before? That is why I was looking for an alternative method. I am not quite sure however!

Comment: @maac `ngrx` doesn't save you from subscribing to observables.

Comment: @Envil I see. But when is an appropiate time to subscribe to my observables? When I set my vehicles$ in the start, it takes time until I can subscribe to it. If I try to subscribe to my observable in the ngOnInit it will try to subscribe to something thats undefined.

Comment: @maac you can still subscribe in `ngOnInit` but you can put a filter there to filter out the `undefined` results.

Comment: @Envil Ahh okok. Is there any way I can avoid subscribing 2 times? Since --- 
 this.vehicles$ = this.store.select(fromStore.getAllVehicles); ---- is also subscribing to it?

Comment: @maac no, that's not subscribing. You should spend time to understand the fundamental thing first, that's my suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is interested I solved this by subscribing to the store, inside of my ngOnInit and dispatching whenever the data was called for (such as on my update button function)

```
// init selected vehicle details inside of my ngOnInit
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.select(fromStore.getAllVehicleDetail).subscribe(data => {
      this.vehicleDetail = data;
      if (this.vehicleDetail.position) {
        this.setMap();
        this.setMarkers();
      } else {
        this.failSetMap();
        this.setMarkers();
      }
    });
}


click() {
     this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadVehicleDetail()); 
  }
```